# how to get in which table which row id updated by using content observer

Tags: android

class MyContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

```
    public MyContentObserver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Didn't called onChange()( " + selfChange+ ")", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     super.onChange(selfChange);
    // fillList();
    // djss();
      }

}
```

how to get row id in onchange method

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the limitations of the observer, we cannot find the row id of the changed field, observer will be called whenever there is a change, what is the change we cannot know

One way of getting to know the change is, query the database before and after the observer has been called and know the difference .